# Chi-squared values differ heavily when calculated by hand and via MATLAB

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, matlab, goodness-of-fit

(Question duplicated from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565501/chi-squared-values-differ-heavily-when-calculated-by-hand-and-via-matlab) as per suggestion in the comments)

In my assignment, I have to approximate a curve based on $N = 15$ data points, then test what distribution the absolute values of approximation errors fall under.

Mean and sigma of the approx. errors were found to be $M = 0.005$ and $\sigma = 0.042$ respectively. Splitting the error range into $C = 5$ bins, I have observed frequencies $O_i = \{7, 3, 2, 2, 1\}$. Expected values are ${E_i}_{\rm unif.} = \{3, 3, 3, 3, 3\}$ for a uniform distribution, and ${E_i}_{\rm norm.} = \{3.1030, 4.1604, 3.4321, 1.7417, 0.5433\}$ for a normal distribution (found by by using `normcdf` on the bin edges, then finding the difference between each pair of edges, according to my notes and [MATLAB’s own example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bt1xyrb), and multiplying by $N$). From there, $\chi^2$ is easy to calculate using $$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{C} \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}$$ and I get $\chi_{\rm unif.}^2 = 7.3333$ and $\chi_{\rm norm.}^2 = 6.2374$, both falling under $\chi_{\rm crit.}^2 = 9.488$ for a $df = C - 1 = 4$ degree of freedom distribution with $p=0.05$ (based on the table seen [here](https://www.mun.ca/biology/scarr/4250_Chi-square_critical_values.html).

Using MATLAB’s `chi2gof`, however, I get noticeably different results. For both distributions, I use it as

`[h, p, stats]  =  chi2gof(eps, 'Expected', N*pi, 'Edges', intervals, 'Alpha', 0.05);`,

where `intervals` is a vector of edges of the bins, and `N*pi` is the vector of expected values.

With MATLAB, I get $\chi_{\rm unif.}^2 = 4.4444$ and $\chi_{\rm norm.}^2 = 1.1210$, the uniform distribution hypothesis being rejected, $p$-values being $0.0350$ and $0.2897$ for uniform and normal distributions respectively. It also seems like MATLAB pools the bins all the way down to two bins, regardless of whether I provide `'Edges'` or `'NBins'`.

I am completely stumped. Where am I going wrong? While looking up information about chi-squared, I’ve read that generally bins should be chosen to have $\forall i \in [1, C]$ $O_i > 5$, and it would correspond to the post-pooling $O_i$ from MATLAB, which comes out to $\{10, 5\}$.

I know that if my manual calculations are correct, neither hypothesis is rejected and I’d have to use a different criterion (e. g., Cramer-Von Mises), but what if MATLAB is right?

I can update the question with the 15 approx. error values used, if needed.

Comment: Not so sure how this function works but it seems that if you bin your data then you should provide the observed frequencies with the 'Frequency' parameter

Comment: and since you don't seem to be fitting any parameters the number of degrees of freedom should be 5 and not 4

Comment: @J.Delaney Providing `'Frequency'` gives an error about a dimension mismatch with the source data `eps`. Your comment, did, however, prompt me to go on another round of searching for questions about `chi2gof`, and in the comments to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/443557-using-chi2gof-to-test-two-distributions) question I found the `EMin` parameter, tweaking which allowed me to get the proper bins to be used, and this time both chi-squared values matched the ones I found by hand. Thanks!